# XSLT How to substring after 10 characters

Tags: xslt

I use xslt to substring before:

```
            <xsl:element name="mapcat">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(categories,'/')"/>
            </xsl:element>
```

Original:
17845/288323/8844

Result:
17845

Working correct

Now I need substring after 10 characters.

I try:

```
            <xsl:element name="mapcat">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(categories,'1,10')"/>
            </xsl:element>
```

But something went wrong and no working. Can anyone help me correct this code?

Answer (score 0):

> I need substring after 10 characters.

I am guessing you want to do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(original-string, 11)"/>
```

Comment: This code string first 11 characters. 17723/233323/323233 result: 3/323233. I need string after 11 characters so should be: 17723/23332. This working for me: <xsl:value-of select="substring(categories,0,11)"/>

Comment: Well, the **first** 11 characters is one thing and substring **after** 10 characters is another. -- P.S. Note that the count starts at 1, not at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation of the problem wasn't very clear (difficulties with your English perhaps?) but from the example supplied as a comment you want the first 11 characters of the string, which is `substring(xx, 1, 11)`. Supplying 0 (or anything less than 1) as the second argument has the same effect: the actual semantics of `substring(x, a, b)` are to include all characters in x whose position p (counting from 1) satisfies `p>=a and p<(a+b)` -- with additional rules for rounding if the values are not integers.

Comment: Supplying 0 as the second argument has the effect of outputting 10 characters instead of 11.